# Authenticating users on AWS with Cognito for a serverless React web app using codes

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

So here's my scenario, I have a web app developed with a serverless architecture on AWS. I'm using S3 to host my static content and all my server-side codes are implemented in Lambda function and accessed through API Gateway. Now I'm trying to use Cognito and user pools to implement the authentication layer.

I've been following the instructions on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-cognito-user-pools.html) and created a user pool. After I've done that, I can test my user pool by entering a URL like this into the browser's address bar:

```
https://my_subdomain_under_aws/login?response_type=code&client_id=my_app_client_id&redirect_uri=my_callback_url
```

The important part (to me) is `response_type=code` which according the same documentation can also be `response_type=token`. At this point, I'm not sure what their differences are and how should I choose between them.

Anyways, opening the mentioned URL will take you to the AWS default login form. Once the user has been successfully authenticated, the browser will be redirected to the provided `redirect_uri` with an extra parameter like this `/?code=12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012`. At this point, I think I'm supposed to extract the `code` (using Javascript on client-side) and pass it to the API Gateway and use it to authenticate the user. But I'm not sure how. I've found [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html) explaining the steps for tokens, but what about codes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going with the code grant, you need to forward the code to your authentication API backend and get the id_token from it. Alternatively you can store the refresh token in the backend securely so that you can use it to issue new id_tokens before current ones expire. Using this id_token you can invoke your API where you can validate the id_token at API gateway custom authorized Lambda or using Cognito Authorizer.

However, implanting Cognito can be further simplified using [AWS Amplify JS](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify) library. AWS recently introduced this to implement the full authentication flow to minimize the effort.

Comment: Thanks for introducing Amplify library, I will definitely look into it. But going back to the question asked, you are saying that the `code` cannot be consumed directly by API Gateway's authorizer the same way tokens can, right?